# Vector 'no operator "[]" matches these operands' error in Visual Studio watch

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, visual-studio-debugging

When stepping through the following sample code in Visual Studio 2012:

```
std::vector<int> test;
test.resize(1);
test[0] = 4;
```

I can set a watch on test and inspect its 0th element.  However, if I set a watch on test[0], I get the error 'no operator "[]" matches these operands':

[image]

How can I inspect the value of test[0] directly?

Comment: Have you compiled in Release or Debug mode?

Comment: Debug, good question.

Comment: Note that iterators and references are generally invalidated when you call `resize`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ordinarily I'd probably use `push_back` in this situation, but I wanted to show assignment by subscripting.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104959/inspecting-stl-containers-in-visual-studio-debugging

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found one solution which does not depend on the internals of the class. The expanded form of the operator call seems to work for me. In this case it's the following code:

```
v.operator[](0)
```

I tested it in Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: On VS2013, it shows the value once and never updates again

Answer (score 7):

As @NateKohl noted, in Visual Studio 2012 (and possibly earlier versions as well) `v._Myfirst` gives a pointer to the underlying vector data, allowing you to watch the vector as if it were an array.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio doesn't support stl containers' operator[] overloading, you simply have to manually set a watch on the element that you're interested in by selecting it from the list while debugging.

EDIT: if you want to inspect a T object inside a vector, assign it to a T object and set a watch on it instead

Comment: What if the vector has 10000 elements and you want to see element 5000?  Is there a convenient way to do that?

Comment: unfortunately I'm afraid you'll have to do it manually for the first time.

Comment: Regarding your edit: that's not an option if you're stepping through a DLL.  What would you do in that scenario?

Comment: I think that `v._Myfirst[0]` allows you to watch e.g. the 0-th element of `v` (where `_Myfirst` (which might be `_First` or `_M_start`, depending on your VS version) is the name of the vector's internal storage)

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean, but if you don't know the type you can assign it with auto type

Answer (score 1):

if you use **2D** vecotr< vector< string > > dp, and you want to get dp[i][j] in watch window in VS2013, you can use **(dp.operator [ ] (i)).operator [ ] (j)**

vector< vector < string > > dp(n, vector < string >(n, ""));

**(dp.operator [ ] (i)).operator [ ] (j)**