# How can I change the values of elements in a vector from Visual C++'s debugger

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, immediate-window

I'm used to being able to modify collection elements in C# from Visual Studio's Immediate Window. However, in C++, when I attempt to do this with a vector, I get an odd error. First, here's my collection:

```
vector<uint8_t>& data;
```

Now, from the immediate window, after breaking in after data has been populated:

```
data
data { size=74 }      
    [size]: 74  
    [capacity]: 74  
    [0]: 1 '\x1'  
    [1]: 5 '\x5'  
    [2]: 23 '\x17'  
    ...  

data[0] = 0   
no operator "[]" matches these operands
```

Is there some special syntax that I should be using here?

Comment: [This Q is possibly relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17799464/2065121) have you seen it?

Comment: That's essentially what I was getting at. I have marked my question as a dupe. Thanks!