# Unable to see content of STL containers in VS code in Ubuntu

Tags: gdb, vscode-debugger, pretty-print

I am having trouble inspecting `std::set` and `std::map` using the debugger in VS Code. I can see the content of a `std::vector` of my classes, but for `std::set` and `std::map`, I only see the attached photo

[image]

I have followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189683/unable-to-inspect-c-stl-content-in-vs-code) but the solution provided is for Windows users. I have also followed this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1414) and modified my `launch.json`, but adding this only solved the problem for `std::vector`, not for `std::set` or `std::map`. Here is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(gdb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "Build",
      "program": "pathToExecutable",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "/PathToProject/",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Test",
          "text": "python import sys;sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc/python');from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers;register_libstdcxx_printers(None)",
          "ignoreFailures": false
        },
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that I have installed `libstdc++6`:

`libstdc++6 is already the newest version (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04)`.

Also, this path `/usr/share/gcc/python/libstdcxx` exists and contains:
`__init__.py  __pycache__  v6`

Comment: 1) Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) 2) What do you see when you run `info pretty-printer` in your GDB? 2) what version of GDB do you have installed?

Comment: @starball sorry about photo. I edited, but the first image is necessary to explain the problem. As I run `info pretty-printer` in debug console, it returns `-var-create: unable to create variable object`. The version of GDB is `GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1`

Comment: When I run `info pretty-printer` through terminal not GDB console in VS Code environment, I get this: `global pretty-printers:
  builtin
    mpx_bound128`

Comment: what if you run it after loading a program that links with libstdc++?

Comment: @starball Okay, It seems I had not added `libstdc++-v6` to `./gdbinit` I corrected that and now `info pretty-printer` returns me  `libstdc++-v6` as well. But, I'm not able to start debugging. When hitting F5, it says `Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-
interpreter-exec console "python import sys;sys.path.insert(0, ‘/usr/
share/gcc/python’);From libstdcxx.v6. printers import
register_libstdcxx_printers;register_libstdcxx_printers(None)™. Error
while executing Python code.`

Comment: @starball sorry about that. It won't be new information, since adding that line to ./gdbinit or putting that in setupCommnads is the same thing.

Comment: ah apologies. I hadn't noticed it in your launch config.